# Why am I getting error "No valid versions available for undefined" while installing create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm-install

I'm trying to install React through command prompt. NodeJS is already installed.

When I try to run this command:

```
npm i -g create-react-app
```

It is displaying error as shown below:

```
npm ERR! code ENOVERSIONS
npm ERR! No valid versions available for undefined

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-10T10_51_39_2222-debug.log
```

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes this can happen when you are using a private NPM registry / proxy registry and it has corrupted metadata.  I've seen this happen with Sonatype Nexus 3 - there were corresponding error messages in the server logs.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the right Node version? Try updating NodeJS or try running: npx create-react-app my-app

Comment: The issue was resolved. When I tried to run the same command again next day it was working fine. Maybe some issue with npm or node.

Answer (score 0):

you should check this out [issue](https://github.com/rolodato/gitlab-letsencrypt/issues/43).

If the problem still exist, please check your versions with this:

```
npm -v  
node -v
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this error came up because I had a version number that did not exist for a package I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue this morning, and my solution was to click on the log file.

It showed me this:

```
2992 verbose type range
2993 verbose stack Error: No valid versions available for undefined
2993 verbose stack     at pickManifest (C:\Program Files\choco\nodejs-14\14.17.1.2108041435\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-pick-manifest\index.js:39:11)
2993 verbose stack     ...etc...
```

So, I opened the file which threw the exception:

C:\Program Files\choco\nodejs-14\14.17.1.2108041435\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-pick-manifest\index.js

and changed line 39 from:

```
err = new Error(`No valid versions available for ${packument.name}`)
```

to

```
err = new Error(`No valid versions available for ${JSON.stringify(packument)}`)
```

I then re-ran "npm install", and this time, it showed the cause of the problem (I've split the one line into several lines, for readability):

```
npm ERR! No valid versions available for {
  "dist-tags":{}, 
  "versions":{},
  "success":false,
  "time":{
    "created":"2023-05-15T20:42:01.119Z",
    "modified":"2023-05-15T20:48:12.712Z"
  },
  "error":"Failed to stream response due to: Missing blob for crypto-js. 
     Unable to check remote crypto-js for retrieving latest copy.",
  "_cached":true,
  "_contentLength":0
}
```

So, this shows me that the cause of the problem is the package:

```
"crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
```

So, I needed to grab one of the valid versions from:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js?activeTab=versions

You can also see why the error message was so hopeless.

```
Error: No valid versions available for undefined
```

Line 39 was attempting to display "name" from this error record, but there was no such field.